# Dropdown styling in yii

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, yii

I am trying to theme my application. For the active drop down list, from my CSS, the following style is called,

```css
.inputs {
  width: 635px;
  float: left;
}

.inputs select[id="Model_attribute"]{
  float: left;
  padding: 9px 9px 9px;
  width: 278px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border:none;
}
```

The following is the generated html

```html
<div class="inputs">
<select name="Model[attribute]" id="Model_attribute">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="26">Option 1</option>
<option value="28">Option 2/option>
</select>   
</div>
```

Following is the view file

```php
    <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'attribute', $model->getOptions(),array(
                 'prompt'=>$hname,
                'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'id'=>'id',
                'url'=>MyController::createUrl('loadOptions'),
                'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'attribute2'),
 
              'data'=>array('attribute'=>'js:this.value'),
   )
        )); ?>
```

When I tested it as an html file, the style got applied, but when I call it in my original form, the style is not coming. I inspected it with firebug ,but no style is showing. Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is style is not coming up or relevant active class is not adding up ?

Comment: Eh, do you mean `.inputs select#Model_attribute`?

Comment: Style is not coming up! Its applied when calling as an html file. But not when called as php through my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yii, you can specify something like the following inside your `activeDropDownList`

```
array('class'=>'yourCssClass')
```

then in your stylesheet :

```
.yourCssClass{
   //any styles
}
```

This should do it for you.

Note : Make sure you are including the proper stylesheet. Try clearing browser cache/history also.

Edit :

Your completed drop down widget will look like :

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'attribute', $model->getOptions(),array(
      'prompt'=>$hname,
      'class'=>'yourCssClass',
      'ajax' => array(
      'type'=>'POST',
      'id'=>'id',
      'url'=>MyController::createUrl('loadOptions'),
      'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'attribute2'),
      'data'=>array('attribute'=>'js:this.value'),
   )
)); ?>
```

and repeat the same for all drop down lists. If the styling is same, just use the same class and if styles are different , then use a different class accordingly.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I want to put my drop down inside my wrapper ie,'inputs' in my style and to apply the style of 'select[id="Model_attribute"]' for my dropdown field.There are many other fields in the 'inputs'. How can i do with your suggestion?

Comment: the best way will be to go as per yii standards, for each of your drop down, simply add style to your existing code. ill modify a bit.

Comment: When i give it as 'class'=>'inputs',i ll get it as with a width of 635px,but i need the width as only 278px..but inside the 'inputs'.How is that possible? :-(

Comment: specify something like `.inputs{ width: 278px !important; }` in your stylesheet. Basically just over-riding the default width.

Comment: Tried..but no use!! :-(

Comment: What do you get on firebug for the particular style? also if you can provide  link to the same, maybe i can take a dig in.

Comment: When i rename my '.inputs select[id="Model_attribute"]' to '.xyz' and give it as  'class'=>'xyz',its not wrking..but for  'class'=>'inputs',atleast it is showing the style. Y is it so?

Comment: because you are trying to over-ride the default yii style(`'.inputs'`), its always better to give a class as suggested in the proper way. and then over-ride values by good use of `!important` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your View, You are generating the dropDown with 'attribute'. Here, Yii will generate dynamic ID for that dropDown by concatenating both model and the model field ie, 'attribute'.

EX: if your

```
          $model=new Country(); //Country is the lable here
```

Now ID will be generated as

```
         <select id='Country_attribute' .......

         .........

         </select>
```

So write the Style for that ID

```
        #Country_attribute
        {
            //Style
        }
```

Comment: I know that Hearaman..i did in the same way only..! I am using the Yii generated id. I just edited it when i posted it as qstn..!!